# Google Analytics Set Up

Tags: google-analytics

I am brand new to the small business I'm working at and I suggested we implement Google Analytics on our website to help track traffic flow.

Well, I am not exactly computer tech savy and am having a difficult time know how to link the Tracking ID to our web pages. Am I really supposed to edit the code on every web page I'd like to track? If so, how does one even "edit code".

Thanks for the insight,

Dana

Answer (score 1):

yes, the code does need to be on every page that you want to track - there should be a code like this which you get from your admin section:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

This needs to be on every page. In answer to how to "edit code", it depends on your website. It is probably easiest to just send your code snippet to whoever built the website and ask them to place it in the head of every page - they will have an easy way to do it via a content management system or tag management system.